# jbpm installation guide error , content folder missing

Tags: jbpm, businesscentral

i am new to jbpm and i am doing a setup as indicated in the documentation , but cant access business-central. Logs tells me that :

> Class Path entry serializer.jar in /C:/Users/Aziz/Desktop/jbpm/jbpm-server-7.74.1.Final-dist/bin/content/business-central.war/WEB-INF/lib/xalan-2.7.3.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.

but there is not content folder somehow.